# "Permission denied" in web server (CentOS on Mediatemple)

Tags: linux, php, permissions, bash

I've made another post regarding gitolite that I've resolved already but this is beginning to aggravate me. I can see that my files have read permissions but my error log continues to produce `"Permission denied"`, `"Failed opening ... for inclusion"`, and `"Unknown: Failed opening required"` errors.

On the website, `mchat.php` is displaying a blank page. I turned out error reporting but nothing came up.

```
[Sun Oct 31 17:21:05 2010] [error] [client 76.95.40.61] PHP Warning:
include(./mchat.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]
: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/vhosts/website
.com/httpdocs/index.php on line 267

[Sun Oct 31 17:21:05 2010] [error] [client 76.95.40.61] PHP Warning:
include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed op
ening './mchat.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:') in /var/www/vhos
ts/website.com/httpdocs/index.php on line 267

[Sun Oct 31 17:21:07 2010] [error] [client 79.105.140.245] PHP Fatal e
rror:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/vhosts/website.com/
httpdocs/mchat.php' (include_path='.:') in Unknown on line 0
```

As you can see, I'm receiving three different errors. Is one of them causing the others?

`ls -l` returns:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 git psacln  8824 Oct 31 22:53 index.php
drwxr-xr-x  2 git psacln  4096 Oct 31 22:53 mchat
-rw-r--r--  1 git psacln 38964 Nov  1 00:02 mchat.php
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please add output of 'ls -ald /', 'ls -ald /var', 'ls -ald /var/www' upto directory '/var/www/vhosts/website.com'. Also give output of 'getenforce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELinux might be enabled. Either use

```
chcon -R -t httptd_sys_content_t <folder>
```

or

```
setenforce 0
```

If you do not use SELinux then you might consider disabling it permanently. Though learning/using it is always a good idea.

Comment: I executed "chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t httpdocs" from root and got this: "chcon: httpdocs: Operation not supported"

Comment: I just disabled selinux and nothing happened.

Comment: Saurabh, your answer worked for my problem.  I'm working with CentOS for the first time, and had a problem with a PHP webapp trying to move an uploaded file from /tmp to a directory under /var/mycompany.  Calls to move_uploaded_file failed with the message "Permission denied", even though the destination directory existed, and was owned by the user as the httpd process.  I invoked `setenforce 0`, and the problem was solved.  I wasn't familiar with SELinux before, and didn't know to check for it. Thanks for the answer!